# Selecting a link-button with the DomCrawler

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm writing functional tests for my Symfony application.

However, i haven't found a way to click on a link button like this one

```
<a id="update" title ="Edit this folder" name="update" href="{{ path('folder_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">
    <button class="button-strong">
        Edit
    </button>
</a>
```

I try to click on it this way :

```
 $link = $crawler->selectLink("Edit")->link();
 $client->click($link);
```

I've tried many others ways but without any success.But when I'm running the tests he keeps  throwing this exception :

```
InvalidArgumentException : The current node list is empty
```

I've looked if there is a way to just click on a button but it seems to be impossible if there is no form linked to it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, having a `<button>` inside a `<a>` is invalid in HTML 5 and may not work as expected.

Coming to the answer, the reason you are getting that error is due to the difference in whitespace. The crawler will not ignore the whitespace and will thus not find a link that has the text **EDIT**.

**HTML**

```
<a id="update" title ="Edit this folder" name="update" href="#">Edit</a>
```

**TEST**

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link();
$client->click($link);
```

Comment: Thank you. I worked my way arround by deleting the button tags and adding a class on my links to look alike.